# Multiple cameras in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to have multiple cameras rendering at the same time for my game engine. My problem is, my vertex shader takes in a single view matrix which means I can't have multiple cameras. I was thinking about how I could change it and lots of google searches later came up with nothing. Not asking for code necessarily but any articles or pointers in the right direction would be very helpful. My vertex shader is down below.

```
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexTextureCoordinate;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 vertexNormal;

out vec3 vertex_position;
out vec3 vertex_color;
out vec2 vertex_textureCoord;
out vec3 vertex_normal;

out vec4 worldPosition;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    worldPosition = model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * worldPosition;

    vertex_position = vec4(vec4(vertexPosition, 1.f) * model).xyz;
    vertex_color = vertexColor;
    vertex_textureCoord = vertexTextureCoordinate;
    vertex_normal = (model * vec4(vertexNormal, 0.0f)).xyz;
}
```

Comment: You have to render the scene separately for each camera. Or use [Layered rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for layered rendering. After reading some articles, it looks like it covers exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: **Even though @Rabbid76 's answer is the best for this situation**; you could also use the help of just simple `FBOs` instead of `layered FBOs` that have to go through the complicated `GS`; and render each camera scene to a new frame buffer and conveniently use the cameras you want through their respective frame buffers that are bound. Read more about `FBOs` here [FrameBuffers: Advanced OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)

Comment: @SnipingPoodle I don't know if this is the "best" solution. Geometry shaders are often slow. Anyway it is a possible solution.

Comment: It is not clear what is "multiple cameras rendering". Does it mean that you need to have several viewports on the screen with corresponding cameras?

Comment: What i was aiming for was two cameras at multiple positions while being able to view both at the same time. I was going for a game engine type thing where there is a scene and game viewport.